# Inconsistency in a simulation using Multisim

Tags: simulation, multisim

After simulating the following circuit in Multisim :[image]

I got these timing diagrams (1 ms/Div and 5 V/Div) :

[image]

I think that the output **Q** is inconsistent , shouldn't it look like this instead  ? :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big problem is that it could be either waveform - the data needs to be setup prior to clocking the 7474 flip flop. It is a positive edge driven device and if you setup data at the instant it receives a positive clock edge then you cannot guarantee what the data is. The fact that your simulator model decides to assume the data is high when the clock rises and is low on the next clock edge is irrelevant because you need to drive the flip flop correctly or you'll get garbage in real life and lies in the simulator.

Setup and hold times for a flip flop: -

[image]

Comment: are you actually referring to the hold time ? because according to 7474 datasheet  it's around 5 ns so this might  be the cause of the problem ,isn'it ?

Comment: @Hilbert no, I'm referring to exactly what I said, the setup time. The hold time is hardly a problem in this design because the data is held for nearly 1 ms after clock has risen. Setup time (20 ns) means the data MUST BE present and stable 20 ns before the rising clock edge.

Comment: But according to the timing diagrams above we can see that the data is also stable  before the rising edge for 1 ms or did I misunderstood something ?

[link](https://imgur.com/a/wKXR9ME)

Comment: The data needs to be stable prior to the rising clock edge. All your digrams show is that the data changes at the rising clock edge and that is the problem. I cannot tell from those diagrams if the data is stable for at least 20 ns prior to the rising clock edge. Can you?

Comment: Could you please the link in my previous comment ?

Comment: See my added picture.

Comment: Thank you now I can clearly see my mistake : during the setup time the data is actually going from high to low , and so this is why the output was unpredictable ,  but there is still a little thing that is bothering me , while going through Tocci's Digital systems Principle and Applications , he included this following example  ([link](https://imgur.com/a/I7FE8ub)) which seems to contradict the principle above .

Comment: That is for a JK flip flop and not a D type flip flop. Apart from that the diagram and words are wrong. If the JK only responds at T2 then how can it respond just prior to T2 (as stated)? Smells very fishy. If in doubt, read the data sheet.

Comment: After reading again the conversation I see that what I've said before was correct , the data DOES hold before the rising edge of the clock , it doesn't hold DURING the rising edge : when the clock goes form low to high , the data input goes from high to low  ,but the input is clearly stable at high BEFORE this upward transition of the clock , and so the setup time requirement is clearly met , and the author was actually correct , when he said that the JK will respond at T2 just prior to T2 , he meant that the input states that'll be considered are those prior to T2 (i.e : J=0 and K=0).

Comment: You are running a simulation of a 7474 and the model it uses will not behave like a real 7474 in all aspects. Regards the author of the document about a JK flip-flop I don't see the relevance; I just see a contradiction in that picture and that contradiction is (anyway) irrelevent to your question. Your question is about a 7474 D type flip flop. It requires 20 ns setup time and 5 ns hold time. If your data changes in that 25 ns period of time then you are illegally using the chip and your sim may or may not reflect this situation (because it is a model).

Comment: *the data DOES hold before the rising edge of the clock* - no, I think you mean the data sets up before the rising edge of the clock. If it does not hold for at least 5 ns after the rising clock then it is an illegal and unpredictable situation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87087/discussion-between-hilbert-and-andy-aka).